# Trigger is not working?

Tags: apex, trigger

I am getting the following error: **execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.FinalException: Record is read-only** I am changing the record type based on the device type which is a picklist field and has 3 possible values. What I want to achieve is that the record type and device type are the same all the time. I already have all the permissions to see and edit the record.

```
trigger UpdateRecordTypeBasedOnDeviceType on Product__c (after insert, after update) {

    // Get a list of record types.
    Map<ID,RecordType> typeMap = New Map<ID,RecordType>([Select ID, DeveloperName From RecordType Where sObjectType = 'Product__c']);
    id Inq = Schema.SObjectType.Product__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('BloodTest').getRecordTypeId(); 
    for (Product__c pt : trigger.new)
    { 
        // If the Record Type = BloodTest
        if (pt.RecordTypeId == Inq)
        {
            // And the Device type on the record =Service 
            if (pt.Device_Type__c == 'Service')
            {
                pt.RecordTypeID =Schema.SObjectType.Product__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('BloodTest').getRecordTypeId();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use an `Apex Trigger` to perform field updates, use a `before trigger`. From the `Apex Developer Guide` on [Triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm) (emphasis mine):

> There are two types of triggers:
>
> - *Before triggers* are used to **update or validate record values** before they’re saved to the database.
> - *After triggers* are used to access field values that are set by the system (such as a record's Id or LastModifiedDate field), and to affect changes in other records, such as logging into an audit table or firing asynchronous events with a queue. The records that fire the after trigger are read-only.